# What technique should i use to replicate the Compose email view in an iphone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I have an Application that involves sending emails through an API.  What I would like is that to have the same or similar to compose email interface available on the phone already.

Unfortunately in all apples Goodness there is no view that just does that.

> [AppleComposeMailViewController alloc];

Would do the trick nicely.

So I have started down the strategy of using a UItableViewController. I have had sucess until i try and Add a dynamically expanding cell on the end for Content.

Should I keep  down this path or try implementing from the UIScrollView Base?

If the Table view is the way to go how would i go about getting a TextView into the Last cell that expands as a user types.

IF I go UIScrollView, what are some strategies i can use to make implementing the top table like views easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the great 'e-mail' composer in the [Three20 framework](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) ([screenshot](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3462/3378171111_666173111d_o.jpg))

Answer (score 5):

In App Email is available in iPhone OS 3.0 and should do just what you describe. Check out MessageUI.

Comment: Any more details?  a link or directions to find docs in the SDK?

Comment: iPhone OS 3.0 is in beta at the moment.  If you are a registered developer($99) you can find the SDK at developer.apple.com/iphone.  The documentation comes with the SDK.

Comment: The class you want is MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: This would work great except it appears that the email needs to be queued into the Mail App. I want to actually send via an API any ideas?